# Javascript. Identifying the mental content

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fetch, comparison, distance

I've posted here a bit about what I call "mindgraphy":https://mindgraphy.eu/
I have no work experience, only some programming knowledge. I have the following problem:

- I collect data from the user according to the form here: https://mindgraphy.eu/index.php/home/sys-see-your-soul
  at the end can form a multidimensional array,
- I have a list of multidimensional arrays attached to a 99 word.
  These arrays are in a file called "w100.js".
  All arrays consist of integers.
  How can I write a javascript that makes a comparison (maybe using Manhattan distance) between array "sP" and arrays from "w100.js" where I have the names of the 10 most similar arrays.
  I have tried several variants but cannot fetch the w100.js file. How can I write a javascript that makes a comparison (maybe using Manhattan distance) between array "sP" and arrays from "w100.js" where I have the names of the 10 most similar arrays.

Comment: That depends on how your `w100.js` looks like. But actually I'd suggest to store your data(?) not in a `.js` file but a `.json` file, which then you can easily fetch in your javascript using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)